Quick question about correction to a typo in an example about the directed system of abelian groups?
Background
The following is taken from:  Graduate Course In Algebra, A - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Example
We consider the category of Abelian groups, and let $(A_i),(f_{ij}), i,j\in I$ be a direct system of Abelian groups.  Then,
$$\varinjlim_{i\in I}A_i=\oplus_{i\in I} A_i/H$$
Where $H$ is the subgrroup of $\oplus A_i$, generated by the set
$$\{f_{ij}(x_i)-x_i\text{ where }i\preceq j, x_i\in A_i\}$$.
Questions:
I have a quick question about the example above.  What should the correct notation for the set $\{f_{ij}(x_i)-x_i\text{ where }i\preceq j, x_i\in A_i\}$ be?  There is a typo, but I am not sure what the correction is suppose to be.
Thank you in advance

Thank you for proper use of mark-down.

@ArturoMagidin I have no idea what you are talking about.  As long as you are happy, then i am happy too.

I am thanking you for doing the post with mark-up, rather than as you had done it in the past. It is meant to be sincere.

What makes you think there is a typo? They are just eliding the canonical inclusions of $A_k$ into $\oplus A_i$.

There is nothing terrible with the notation. It is clear and understandable. Writing it out precisely would be harder to parse. Something like $${a\in \oplus A_k\mid \exists i,j\in I,\exists x( i\preceq j\wedge x\in A_i\wedge a=\iota_j(f_{ij}(x))-\iota_i(x)}$$ where $\iota_k\colon A_k\to \oplus A_i$ are the canonical inclusions.

Isn't direct limit defined as quotient by $f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_j)$ for some $k$? Is that the same thing?

@ArturoMagidin I have never seen:  ${f_{ij}(x_i)-x_i\text{ where }i\preceq j, x_i\in A_i}$.  I would have thought to be written something like ${f_{ij}(x_i)=x_i\mid\text{ where }i\preceq j, x_i\in A_i}$. Also what is "$${a\in \oplus A_k\mid \exists im"?

@freakish Yes, it is the same thing. cf. this, this.

@Seth it's the result of accidental premature posting, now fixed.

@ArturoMagidin $\iota_j$ $\iota_i$ are both inclusion maps?

@freakish more precisely, if there is a $k$ with $f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_k)$, then you want $x_i=x_j$ in the quotient. If that happens, then $H\ni x_i-x_j = (f_{jk}(x_j)-x_j)-(f_{ik}(x_i)-x_i)$. Conversely, you have $f_{ij}(x_i) = f_{jj}(f_{ij}(x_i))$, so you want to identify $x_i$ and $f_{ij}(x_i)$ in the quotient.

@Seth Isn't that clear from the syntax of my sentence? "where $\iota_k\colon A_k\to \oplus A_i$ are the canonical inclusions" (emphasis added).

@ArturoMagidin it is more clear now that you explicitly written out the map.  :)

@Seth "now"? I had that before. I am literally just repeating what I said before.
